# How do I use filters on multiple layers in Kartograph?

Tags: shapefile, javascript, kartograph

I am trying to create a map of the continental US and Puerto Rico using Kartograph. I am using the shapefiles from Natural Earth, and I obtained the filter keys from the column headers of the `DBF` files for each data set. My intuition tells me to first add only Puerto Rico from `ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp`, and then add the Continental US states from `ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp`. My `config.json` file is as follows:

```
{
    "layers": {
        "world": {
            "src": "ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes/ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp",
            "filter": ["gu_a3", "is", "PRI"]
        },
        "states": {
            "src": "ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes/ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp",
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    ["sr_adm0_a3", "is", "USA"],
                    ["postal", "is not", "AK"],
                    ["postal", "is not", "HI"]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run `kartograph`:

```
$ kartograph config.json -o config.svg
```

I end up with a map of only Puerto Rico:

[image: Puerto Rico]

If I reverse the order of the layers in the `JSON`, I get a map of the Continental US but not Puerto Rico:

[image: Continental US]

How do I prevent the filters on the first layer from cropping out everything on the second layer?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `bounds` part like below

```
{
    "layers": {
        "world": {
            "src": "ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes/ne_50m_admin_0_countries_lakes.shp",
            "filter": ["gu_a3", "is", "PRI"]
        },
        "states": {
            "src": "ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes/ne_50m_admin_1_states_provinces_lakes.shp",
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    ["sr_adm0_a3", "is", "USA"],
                    ["postal", "is not", "AK"],
                    ["postal", "is not", "HI"]
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "bounds": {
         "mode": "bbox", 
         "data": [-126, 12, -59, 54]
    }
}
```

For reference, you can take a look at [the related documentation](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.py/#clipping-to-a-longitude/latitude-range-%28bbox%29).